# Running JUnit-Tests that uses SWT-Display fails on Jenkins

Tags: swt, jenkins

I a have a few JUnit-Tests that makes use of the current Display to instantiate a few controls (TreeViewer for instance). Locally that works fine, no problem. When I commit these tests and jenkins runs the test I get a failed test for each test that makes use of Display.

My unit test uses the display variable in this manner:

```
@Test
public void testUtils() {
    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display, SWT.NONE);
    // org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite composite = new
    // org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite(
    // shell, SWT.NONE);
    TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
            | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

The error log jenkins generates is:

```
Time elapsed: 0.13 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4109)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1693)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:253)
    at
```

Is there any thing wrong with the way I am using Display in my tests? It works when executed on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

The way you use Display looks OK to me. The error is likely related to the fact that your server is not running Gnome, hence SWT can't create a Display when you ask it to.

**UPDATE**

I just found a recent blog post, which explains what you need to do to [run SWT UI tests on a headless server](http://community.bonitasoft.com/blog/how-run-ui-tests-hudsoneclipseorg-server-server-without-window-manager-activated-default) in more detail. Although the steps provided are meant for Hudson, they should be applicable to Jenkins as well.

It should all boil down to these two steps:

> - Check *Run Xvnc during build* (and don’t bother to check take screenshot, it doesn’t work)
> - Add an *Execute shell* build action before launching your tests with *metacity –replace –sm-disable &*

See the linked blog post for screenshots and more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following two things,

1. execute command "xhost" or "xhost+" from your terminnal.
2. execute command "xhost" or "xhost+" from, jenkins terminal.